# How to find the nearest patch in 3D model?

Tags: netlogo

How can a turtle find the nearest patch in 3D model? For 2D model, the code should be like this.

```
    let nearest min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green] ) [distance myself] ;
```

However, I tried to use distancexyz, and it does not work and it requires x, y and z coordinators. I am not sure how to get those coordinators of a turtle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code should work in 3D as in 2D.

Comment: Hi Seth, Thank you very much for your reply. I tried it yesterday, and it works in both 2D and 3D. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`distancexyz`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/3d.html#distancexyz) takes coordinates as arguments, not an agent (patches are agents). You want `distance`, as in `distance nearest`.